# Python Curses Handling Window (Terminal) Resize

Tags: python, resize, curses

This is two questions really:

- how do I resize a curses window, and
- how do I deal with a terminal resize in curses?

Is it possible to know when a window has changed size?

I really can't find any good doc, not even covered on http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Terminal resize event will result in the `curses.KEY_RESIZE` key code. Therefore you can handle terminal resize as part of a standard main loop in a curses program, waiting for input with `getch`.

Comment: This is right, but only when ncurses is compiled with --enable-sigwinch. In particular, the libncurses in Debian and Ubuntu doesn't have that turned on; I'm not sure why.

Comment: @thepaul: at least in my Ubuntu 12.04 I do get `curses.KEY_RESIZE` code when I resize the terminal emulator window.

Comment: Good, I'm glad they fixed that.

Answer (score 10):

I got my python program to re-size the terminal by doing a couple of things.

```
# Initialize the screen
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()

# Check if screen was re-sized (True or False)
resize = curses.is_term_resized(y, x)

# Action in loop if resize is True:
if resize is True:
    y, x = screen.getmaxyx()
    screen.clear()
    curses.resizeterm(y, x)
    screen.refresh()
```

As I'm writing my program I can see the usefulness of putting my screen into it's own class with all of these functions defined so all I have to do is call `Screen.resize()` and it would take care of the rest.

Comment: Could you add whatever is needed to make this code self-contained?  For example I'm not sure what "screen" is.

Comment: @DonHatch Hopefully that is what you are looking for.  Here is a good little tutorial also if you are wanting it. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: He meant that your code doesn't work if you just copy and past to test it as there are many things missing.

Comment: where do you take `y, x` in `resize = curses.is_term_resized(y, x)` ? is it old sizes? If so, how do you get the terminal size? for me, `screen.getmaxyx()` doesn't seem to return the updated size. When I change the size of command line, it is still the same...

Answer (score 5):

I use the code from [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-February/426098.html).

In my curses-script I don't use getch(), so I can't react to `KEY_RESIZE`.

Therefore the script reacts to `SIGWINCH` and within the handler re-inits the curses library. That means of course, you'll have to redraw everything, but I could not find a better solution.

Some example code:

```
from curses import initscr, endwin
from signal import signal, SIGWINCH
from time import sleep

stdscr = initscr()

def redraw_stdscreen():
    rows, cols = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.border()
    stdscr.hline(2, 1, '_', cols-2)
    stdscr.refresh()

def resize_handler(signum, frame):
    endwin()  # This could lead to crashes according to below comment
    stdscr.refresh()
    redraw_stdscreen()

signal(SIGWINCH, resize_handler)

initscr()

try:
    redraw_stdscreen()

    while 1:
        # print stuff with curses
        sleep(1)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
except Exception as e:
    pass

endwin()
```

Comment: Calling endwin/initscr in a signal handler is a good way to get core dumps.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks for the info. I've removed one initscr() from the signal-handler, what presumably doesn't improve it much. The c-code in an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13707598/3469861), recommends to use `endwin()` followed by `refresh()`. Am I right, that python3 would inform about the user about the coredump? If yes, I hadn't have one up to now, while furiously resizing my terminal.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when using [curses.wrapper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html?highlight=wrapper#curses.wrapper):

```
if stdscr.getch() == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
    curses.resizeterm(*stdscr.getmaxyx())
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()
```

Comment: I tried this using terminal inside **VS Code** and was stuck in the loop most probably because of infinitely repeating `curses.KEY_RESIZE` events. A call to `curses.flushinp()` didn't help. A pity... this answer helped me the best, nevertheless.

Comment: @qdbp infinitely repeating `curses.KEY_RESIZE` events?  If you can't depend on `stdscr.getch()`, I guess you'll just have to keep track of when `stdscr.getmaxyx()` returns new values.

Comment: In my Curses / Python installation, the function name is `resize_term` not `resizeterm`. Also the curses documentation page you referred to has `resize_term` .

Answer (score -2):

It isn't right.  It's an `ncurses-only` extension.  The question asked about `curses`.  To do this in a standards-conforming way you need to trap `SIGWINCH` yourself and arrange for the screen to be redrawn.

Comment: This is talking about Python's curses library which actually wraps the ncurses library.