# ncurses window resizing patterns

Tags: c, resize, ncurses

I have seen some other questions on SO dealing with window resizing, e.g., [ncurses - resizing glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707137/ncurses-resizing-glitch)

The code in that question has a for loop to redraw the contents of the window *after* the resize.

My question is:  is it possible, rather than reprinting the window after the call to `clear()` and before the call to `refresh()`, to have curses use the text that's already in the output buffer?

I.e., to "reflow" the text, rather than clear/ reprint?

I have a rather complicated ncurses application with multiple windows being updated by multiple threads and I can't really see a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, no there is no way to "reflow" or have ncurses handle the adjustment of the text.

However you could use the panels library (which is part of ncurses) to handle the windows. With panels you can attach arbitrary user data via [set_panel_userptr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/set_panel_userptr). You could use this to store a callback function with each panel that can resize the content.

Your resize handler can loop through all of the panels calling the resize callback.

As a side note, ncurses is not thread safe. Make sure your threads are using ncurses safely.

Comment: So are you telling me that elinks and cmus and vichess and <insert ncurses program here> all have reflow code?  If so, can you point me to the "right way" / common pattern for doing this?  I can't find this anywhere.