# Terminal control library that blocks on both input and some custom data channel?

Tags: ncurses, curses

ncurses' blocking mode appears to only allow for blocking on stdin - that is, I have no option of doing some `select()`-esque thing where `getch()` blocks until *either* a key is pressed *or* e.g. data arrives in a pipe. Am I missing something, or is there some other terminal control library that allows me to do this?

Edit: I'm targeting Linux platforms, although the more general the solution, the better.

Comment: Apparently, the behavior of `getch()` is not portable, (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30433550/8507637). It would be helpful to include the operating system you are targeting.

Answer (score 2):

There's an experimental [configure-option](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/1016d93ea952ba5e78bca2dda65da5587206b906/INSTALL#L745), which is rarely used:

> **`--enable-wgetch-events`**
>   Compile with experimental wgetch-events code. See [ncurses/README.IZ](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/README.IZ)

Comment: this is interesting, although because i'm using a non-C language, making use of this feature would require both compiling and shipping a custom version of ncurses with my program and also creating my own FFI wrapper to expose `wgetch_events()` and `wgetstrn_event()` in addition to the "standard" functions. if necessary, i'll do this, but if there's something easier i would rather use that.

Comment: @fouric which language are you using?

Comment: @LucasRamage Common Lisp