# Ncurses and Resizing window

Tags: c, ncurses

I tried to enter text at the bottom of window and print it on the top. I did this. But when I resize the window, cursor is attached to the bottom of the window and when I type the text, symbols do not echo on the screen. How fix it?

Sorry for my English.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <signal.h>

WINDOW* txt_win;
WINDOW* msg_win;


void sig_winch(int in) {

    struct winsize size;
    ioctl(fileno(stdout), TIOCGWINSZ, (char*) &size);
    resizeterm(size.ws_row, size.ws_col);
    // wprintw(msg_win,"%i, %i", LINES, COLS);
    // wmove(msg_win, 0, 0);
    // wresize(msg_win, LINES - 4, COLS);
    wrefresh(msg_win);
    // mvcur(LINES - 3, 0, LINES - 3, 0);
    // setsyx(LINES - 3, 0);
    // wmove(txt_win, LINES - 3, 0);
    // wresize(txt_win, 3, COLS);
    wrefresh(txt_win);
    echo();

   }

int main() {

        int x = LINES - 1;
        int y = 0;

        if (!initscr())
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error initialising ncurses.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        signal(SIGWINCH, sig_winch);

        initscr();
        curs_set(1);
        refresh();

        char str[256];
                    //   dy   dx         y         x
        msg_win = newwin(LINES - 4, COLS, 0, 0);
        txt_win = newwin(3, COLS,       LINES - 3, 0);
        keypad(txt_win, 1);

        int line = 0;
        while (1) {

            wrefresh(txt_win);
            curs_set(1);
            if (wgetnstr(txt_win, str, 256) == 0) {
                wclear(txt_win);
                curs_set(0);
                waddstr(msg_win, str);
                wrefresh(msg_win);
            }
        }


    getch();

    delwin(txt_win);
    delwin(msg_win);

    endwin();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

- ncurses already handles `SIGWINCH`, as noted in the [`resizeterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html) manual page.
- if you did not add your own handler for `SIGWINCH`, you could (if you first called `keypad(stdscr,TRUE)`) check for `KEY_RESIZE`.
- the functions used in your signal handler are not safe to use; the program could fail for a number of reasons.

`KEY_RESIZE` is discussed in *[ncurses - resizing glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707137/ncurses-resizing-glitch?rq=1)*, for instance.