# python curses' getch() returns -1 instead of KEY_RESIZE when terminal is resized. Why?

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I am attempting to create handling for manual terminal resizing in my python program that uses the curses module. After a bit of testing, it seems that when the terminal is manually resized, getch() doesn't return KEY_RESIZE but instead returns -1 (for 'no input'). I tested this with the following code in GNOME Terminal and xterm:

```
import curses


stdscr = curses.initscr()
stdscr.keypad(1)
curses.curs_set(0)
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
while True:
   key = stdscr.getch()
   stdscr.addstr(0,0, '{} PRESSED'.format(key))
```

It also appears that curses' "bookkeeping" data such as LINES and COLS are not updated when the screen is manually resized and getch returns -1, which is proving problematic for making any resize handling function. My questions are:

Why is curses returning -1 instead of KEY_RESIZE?

in the absence of a KEY_RESIZE event, is there any way to update curses' knowledge of the physical terminal's size?

Comment: It's a compile-time option in libcurses whether you get KEY_RESIZE or not.  You can handle it yourself:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161552/python-curses-handling-window-terminal-resize

Comment: None of the answers in the suggested duplicate actually answer this question.  54520435 is closer...